# Can't instantiate public class in the same package

Tags: java, access-modifiers

So I made this java file A.java,

```
package alphabet;


public class A{
   private  String private_A;
   String _A;
   protected String protected_A;
   public String public_A;

   public A(){
      private_A="Private A";
      _A="Package Private A";
      protected_A="Protected A";
      public_A="Public A";
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}
```

and another class in the same package,

```
package alphabet;

import alphabet.A;

public class B{
    void methodB1(){
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A AinB = new A();

    }
}
```

When I compile `B` I can't instantiate `A`.
Why is that? `A` is a public class, and `B` belongs to the same package? Shouldn't `B` be able to make an instance of `A`?

This pretty noobish, but thanks.

**EDIT:** Got these errors,

```
*@*:~/rand$ javac B.java 
B.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import alphabet.A;
               ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: package alphabet
B.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                A AinB = new A();
                ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
B.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                A AinB = new A();
                             ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
3 errors
```

**EDIT**: Removed the import statement still getting these errors

```
B.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                A AinB = new A();
                ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
B.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                A AinB = new A();
                             ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
2 errors
```

Comment: Are you getting a compile error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: _A="Package Private A"; is this correct?

Comment: How did you know that it's not working I'm not seeing any output from the classes

Comment: Remove the import statement

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias Yes, its _A. made the edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your classes are in package alphabet, you need to put them in a subdirectory called alphabet, and then run javac from its parent directory using this command line:

```
javac alphabet/B.java
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks, I knew it was something pretty simple.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is you are compiling it wrong. Since you are using package, while compiling you need to be outside the package.

So instead of `javac B.java`

Make a folder/directory named same as package name i.e. `alphabet` and move the java files to it.

Use `javac alphabet/B.java`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the import statement in class B.  You don't need to import from the same package.

Comment: That makes sense, and that's what I wrote originally but when I got the `cannot find symbol` error, I put in the import. Removed it now and posted the errors without the import

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 main methods, you should only have 1 which is for starting the program off, try creating a A object in be or whatever class you want to run first:

```
package alphabet;


public class A{
 private  String private_A;
String _A;
protected String protected_A;
public String public_A;

public A(){
  private_A="Private A";
  _A="Package Private A";
  protected_A="Protected A";
  public_A="Public A";
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B bclass = new B();
    bclass.yourmethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can have as many main methods as you like, and they don't cause this poblem.